# Is it possible to seed and sync a MongoDB using AngularJS, from an existing API that returns data in json

Tags: angularjs, json, mongodb, mean-stack

Id Like to build a MEAN stack app which would require that I seed and sync a MongoDB using AngularJS from an existing API that returns data in json. Is this possible? or would I have to load the Json manually? and if once the mongodb is up and running how would I then sync any new records that have been created at the API end with the MongoDB?

Comment: I think you are talking about REST apis..so in that case u need to call your API's in some interval to get the updated data..that process is called polling,

Comment: Thankyou @SanjayB, yes do you know of any examples of polling that I could take a look at?